# GitHub - Desktop App Inserts Text Into My Code When I Sync

Tags: github, github-for-windows

When I sometimes use the `GitHub` Desktop App and Sync to get whatever changes were made to repo, it inserts strings into my code like this:

```
>>>>>>> origin/master
```

Why is it doing this? I haven't found anything online that talks about this problem. Am I using the app right? The same thing happens to my coding partners as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>>>>>>> origin/master` is a *merge marker*, which is Git's way of representing merge conflicts in a versioned file.  In the course of updating your local `master` branch it can the case that a change you pulled in from the remote conflicts with the version you have locally.  One example would be a method or function which both you and someone else in your team modified.  Git will first try to automatically resolve this conflict.  But if it cannot, then you will see something looking like the following:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
// your local version
=======
// remote version
>>>>>>> origin/master
```

To resolve this you can use a merge conflict tool.  If you wish to resolve by hand, then you should choose which version you want, possibly modify that as well, and then delete all the markers (i.e. delete `<<<<<<<`, `=======`, and `>>>>>>>`).

Comment: I remember that the desktop app would sometimes show me the conflicts and let me work through them in the app. Why didn't it do it for me this time? Is it because I didn't commit first before syncing?

Comment: If it didn't do it this time, it could be because Git automatically resolved the conflicts.  This is nice, because it means you won't have a headache.

Comment: But it didn't let me work through the conflicts and inserted those strings anyway :(

Comment: What's the difference between the "Sync" and the "Pull Request" on GitHub? Should I only sync when I've committed changes to the repo?

Comment: I believe "sync" will do a `git fetch`, which means it will update your local tracking branches (without merging anything to your true local branches).  A pull request is something entirely different.  A pull request doesn't really exist inside Git, rather it is GitHub's way of representing one branch which can be merged into another.

Comment: Aaaah ok. I ended up deleting all the files in my directory and re-syncing. I then followed the "commit then sync" process and the problem didn't happen again. It was most likely because I didn't commit first before syncing. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Actually, strictly speaking you should not be allowed to do a `git fetch` if your working directory is dirty.  Your approach sounds correct to me.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! I'm relatively new to GitHub and source control so this info is definitely going to help me with my school project.